# Mencoder - Audio is longer than Video Stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mencoder

I am trying use some images and audio to create video using mencoder.
But my audio file could be much longer.

```
Example:
5 images. 
fps: 1
desired video length: 5 seconds
audio file length is: 20 seconds.

mencoder mf://*.jpg -mf fps:1.0 -oac mp3lame -audiofile myaudio.mp3 -ovc lavc vcodec=mpeg4 -o myvideo.mpeg
```

This produces a video that is:
20 seconds long (as long as audio file length).
The image slide show ends at 5 seconds, after that there is only audio playing (from 6th to 20th second).

How can i make mencoder to generate video of only duration where video stream exists. In this case end the video at 5 seconds.

**ffmpeg has a -shortest option for exactly this kind of use case. But i cannot find equivalent of that in mencoder.**

Comment: Why not parse out the duration of streams and then provide the shortest as number of seconds to encode? This is just in case mencoder does not have the option

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?  I just came across the same scenario, and haven't been able to find any info on how to do this with mencoder.